# Git - Save unfinished merge changes and checkout another branch

Tags: git

I'm working on a git branch that has a lot of merge conflicts with another branch that I've merged into it. I started fixing the conflicts but want to save my work and switch to another branch before I finish the merge process.

Is it possible to stash the changes in the unfinished merge process to switch to another branch and then switch back and finish the merge?

I've spent a lot of time working on fixing the conflicts and I don't want to do this work again. What's the best way to proceed?

I'm using git version 1.7.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a merge is a process, you can't stash "changes" in the middle of the process.

Your best bet is to clone the repo into another directory.

PS. Ben is always right.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here as well: **stashing did not work**.
I **copied the whole git-repo locally** to another folder as backup. Continued my work, then for switching back just opened it and continued the resolving of conflicts.